# Regex for comma separated characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to validate a set of non repeating characters separated by commas.

Given the set of characters like ABCD
Match any comma separated permutation (no repeating characters)
Some matches would be:
A
C
C,B
B,D
D,B,A,C
Some no matches would be:
A,A
ABC
D,B,A,B

This would work but doesn't allow the commas:

```
\b(?!(?:.\B)*(.)(?:\B.)*\1)[ABCD]+\b
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't allow the commas"?
you want to match it as a whole, including the commas?

Comment: Is `A,B,` a valid input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*?([A-D]).*?\1)[A-D](?:,[A-D])*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/8

Comment: Nailed it.  Complete and utter Rock and Roll!

Answer (score 5):

Try if something like this would match your needs:

```
^(?:([A-D])(?!.*?\1),)*[A-D]$
```

If there's more than just one `[A-D]`, preceding ones must be followed by a comma, captures prior `[A-D]` to `\1` and checks if not followed by itself using a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mS3tQ7/1); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: Dunno why OP chose mine...Yours is more efficient :)